# How to save and return exit code in makefile target

Tags: shell, makefile

I have a make target that looks something like this:

```
.PHONY: run-my-test
run-my-test: all
    run_test_suite.sh --all --log-to-file
    post_process_logs.sh
```

If a test case fails, the exit code of `run_test_suite.sh` will cause Make to not continue with running `post_process_logs.sh`. This is a problem, because i want to get the processed logs even for failed tests. How should i update my target to do this?

I've thought of saving the exit code somehow and perhaps exit with it in the end of the target definition. Or do I split the calls up into separate targets?

I can add that I'm pretty much forced to do this from Make because of how our build system works. And I would prefer not having to add more targets as the make files tend to be cluttered with these as it is.

Comment: Include a [mre] in your question.

Comment: Just to clarify, if `run_test_suite.sh` fails you still want `post_process_logs.sh` to run but make should then fail at the end of the `run-my-test` rule rather than continue?

Comment: Just like for the presented target, the build should fail if `post_process_logs.sh` exits with an error code.

Comment: You haven't answered @G.M.'s question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the build to fail *after* running `post_process_logs.sh`, put both commands in the same entry.

```
.PHONY: run-my-test
run-my-test: all
        run_test_suite.sh --all --log-to-file; \
        e=$$?; \
        post_process_logs.sh; \
        exit $$e
```

The exit status of `run_test_suite.sh` is saved in the shell variable `e`, which is used as the argument to `exit` after `post_process_logs.sh` to set the exit status of the overall command.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a big logic and don't want to deal with all of this hell:

```
.PHONY: run-my-test
run-my-test: all
    mkdir -p test_reports;
    run_test_suite.sh --all --log-to-file ||\
        echo $$? > test_reports/exit_code.txt && echo "ERROR Tests failed";

    # do some other logic, i.e. make a coverage report
    go tool cover -html=test_reports/coverage.out -o test_reports/coverage.html;

    # more and more other logic

    echo "Exiting with $$(cat test_reports/exit_code.txt)" && exit $$(cat test_reports/exit_code.txt)
```